# CSS Styles accidentally removes my scrollbar in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, scrollbar, wordpress-theming

I'm having trouble with my css styles in wordpress. Chrome is removing my scrollbar, while in IE my page is fixed and doesn't scroll at all. I've disabled my admin bar because it seemed to be causing some trouble, but I still can't see my scrollbar.

Here's my page http://www.kareemkwong.me/

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey Apochocolate, i see you solved your problem. So if the answer below did help you, please accept it, otherwise post your solution. This might help others some day. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As you are using modernizer, it adds the class `video` to your `html` tag automatically. This is to state that your browser supports the video tag.
In your custom stylesheet, however, you also have a custom `video` class with `overflow: hiddden;`. Consequently, your whole page is set to `overflow: hidden`.

You can either

- remove `overflow: hidden` in your custom video class if it is not needed
- rename your custom video class and change the html accordingly
- add an extra class to your videos to handle the overflow
   In your CSS: `.video.noOverflow { overflow: hidden; }`.
  In your HTML: add the `noOverflow` class to the element that already has the `video` class (`class="video noOverflow"`).